# PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher cause ANR

Tags: java, android

Strange call stack when app ANR, dead loop. There is no code related to app itself, PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher called many times in the stack. Does anyone meet the same question?  Many thanks if suggestion provided.
Reproduce step: input number in the recipient area of messaging app.

```
 at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native method)
 at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:748)
 at android.view.autofill.IAutoFillManager$Stub$Proxy.updateSession(IAutoFillManager.java:452)
 at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.updateSessionLocked(AutofillManager.java:879)
  at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyValueChanged(AutofillManager.java:646)
  - locked <0x07dcd96d> (a java.lang.Object)
  at android.widget.TextView.notifyAutoFillManagerAfterTextChangedIfNeeded(TextView.java:9396)
  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9380)
  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:11917)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1266)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:576)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:507)
  at android.telephony.PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java:112)
  - locked <0x0637b466> (a android.telephony.PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher)
  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9375)
  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:11917)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1266)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:576)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:507)
  at android.telephony.PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java:112)
  - locked <0x03c65f17> (a android.telephony.PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher)
  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9375)
  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:11917)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1266)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:576)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:507)
  at android.telephony.PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java:112)
  - locked <0x08b9b6c4> (a android.telephony.PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher)
  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9375)
  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:11917)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1266)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:576)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:507)
  at android.telephony.PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java:112)
```

Comment: post your code..

Comment: PhoneNumberFormatter.setPhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(this, mRecipientsEditor);

Comment: RecipientsEditor extends RecipientEditTextView

Comment: put in separate thread your above code

Comment: yes,         @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher watcher) {
            if (watcher == null || isCancelled()) {
                return; 
            }
            mTextView.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
        }

Comment: Already use async task, just one question : why PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher called so many times in the stack?

Comment: I think your async task called multiple time and your doing operation on the onPostexcute method that is in the main thread that's why ANR is getting...please check your async task calling code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing heavy operation on main thread and if main thread blocked then mostly ANR called.

Try this one it will be helpful for you.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {

                 PhoneNumberFormatter.setPhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(thi‌​s, mRecipientsEditor);
             }
         });
        t.start();
```